# Displaying jQuery Dynamic GeoJSON Content On LeafLet Map

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet, geojson

I am looking to create a leaflet map site that:

- Takes in parameters (a date range) and  press a button
- Performs an SQL Query
- Builds a GeoJSON Extract of the Query Results
- Displays the resulting markers on a leaflet map

I have the first three steps working, but am unable to add the results to an existing map (the basemap has a few kml layers and overlays using omnivore that i want available with or without the queried data).

Here is the HTML

```
<input id="txtStartDate" type="text" class="date-picker/>
<input id="txtEndDate" type="text" class="date-picker/>
<input type="button" id="btnMapIt" value="Map Values" class="btn"/>

<div id="map"></div>
```

Here is the jQuery / JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // Layer Groups
    var layerCityBoundary = new L.LayerGroup();
    var layerCityRoads = new L.LayerGroup();

    // All KML Layer Group (details not reallt important - it works!)
    loadKMLData(layerCityBoundary, 'kml/city_boundary.kml');
    loadKMLData(layerCityRoads , 'kml/city_roads.kml');

    // Map Layers
    var mbAttr = 'Map data &copy',
        mbUrl = 'https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpandmbXliNDBjZWd2M2x6bDk3c2ZtOTkifQ._QA7i5Mpkd_m30IGElHziw';

    var grayscale = L.tileLayer(mbUrl, { id: 'mapbox.light', attribution: mbAttr }),
        streets = L.tileLayer(mbUrl, { id: 'mapbox.streets', attribution: mbAttr });

    var map = L.map('map', {
            center: [45, -80],
            zoom: 12,
            layers: [streets]
        });

    var baseLayers = {
            "Streets": streets,
            "Grayscale": grayscale
        };

    var overlays = {
            "City Boundary": layerCityBoundary ,
            "City Streets": layerCityRoads 
        };

    L.control.layers(baseLayers, overlays).addTo(map);

    //******************************************************************
    // Search Button Press
    //******************************************************************
    $('#btnMapIt').click(function () {

        var startDate = $('#txtStartDate').val();
        var endDate = $('#txtEndDate').val();

        // Run Data Handler Query
        $.ajax({
            url: "queries/dhGetMapPoints.ashx",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json",
            data: { 
                dStartDate: startDate,
                dEndDate: endDate
            },
            responseType: "json",
            success: function (geojson) {

                L.geoJson(geojson, {
                    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                        layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.name);
                    }
                }).addTo(map);

            },
            error: function () {
                alert('ERROR.');
            },
        });

    });

});
```

However, it gives me issues saying the map has already been drawn. How can I add this (and remove any existing) layers from the existing map (but still keep the overlay layers)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my stab at it...I made changes with comments.  I didn't test this, so it may not work first try.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

// Layer Groups
var layerCityBoundary = new L.LayerGroup();
var layerCityRoads = new L.LayerGroup();

// All KML Layer Group (details not reallt important - it works!)
loadKMLData(layerCityBoundary, 'kml/city_boundary.kml');
loadKMLData(layerCityRoads , 'kml/city_roads.kml');

// Map Layers
var mbAttr = 'Map data &copy',
    mbUrl = 'https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpandmbXliNDBjZWd2M2x6bDk3c2ZtOTkifQ._QA7i5Mpkd_m30IGElHziw';

var grayscale = L.tileLayer(mbUrl, { id: 'mapbox.light', attribution: mbAttr }),
    streets = L.tileLayer(mbUrl, { id: 'mapbox.streets', attribution: mbAttr });

var map = L.map('map', {
        center: [45, -80],
        zoom: 12,
        layers: [streets]
    });

var baseLayers = {
        "Streets": streets,
        "Grayscale": grayscale
    };

//pre-create geoJson layer
var geoJsonFeature;
var existGeoJson = L.geoJson(geoJsonFeature, {
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.name);
    }
});

//include geoJson layer in overlays
var overlays = {
        "City Boundary": layerCityBoundary ,
        "City Streets": layerCityRoads,
        "Existing GeoJSON": existGeoJson
    };

L.control.layers(baseLayers, overlays).addTo(map);

//******************************************************************
// Search Button Press
//******************************************************************
$('#btnMapIt').click(function () {

    var startDate = $('#txtStartDate').val();
    var endDate = $('#txtEndDate').val();

    // Run Data Handler Query
    $.ajax({
        url: "queries/dhGetMapPoints.ashx",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        data: { 
            dStartDate: startDate,
            dEndDate: endDate
        },
        responseType: "json",
        success: function (geojson) {
            //loop through your geoJson adding them to your existing layer.
            for (var i = 0; i < geoJson.length; i++) {
            var obj = geoJson[i];
            existGeoJson.addData(obj);
        }


        },
        error: function () {
            alert('ERROR.');
        },
    });

});

});
```

Comment: This is excellent (made a few very minor tweaks). Thank you for the start - but not exactly what I am looking for. I am looking to have the markers placed directly on the map when the button is press - not necessarily as an overlay layer (I don't trust the users enough to know the overlay layer is changing and needs to be selected). Any ideas how to place directly onto the map?

Comment: Figured out my issue. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Good deal, no problem!